# C++ why are typedef structs unique compared to typedef primitives

Tags: c++

Why is a `typedef` for a `struct` considered a unique type while a `typedef` for a `std::string` or other primitive is not? Consider that you could have two `struct`s that have the same components but it is treated as two different, unrelated types.

Here is a working example.

```
#include <iostream>
//#define FAIL
#ifdef FAIL
// These are considered to be the same thing
typedef std::string StringEventA;
typedef std::string StringEventB;
#else
// But these are two entirely different types...
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventA;
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventB;
#endif

class Foo {
    public:
        void Handle(StringEventA event){std::cout<<"A\n";}
        void Handle(StringEventB event){std::cout<<"B\n";}
};

int main()
{
    StringEventA a;
    StringEventB b;
    Foo foo;
    foo.Handle(a);
    foo.Handle(b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because you don't name the structs doesn't mean they are the same type (and if you *did* name them you couldn't give them the *same* name). In contrast, the first typedef's resolve to the *same* std::string type.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by naming the structs. Also is it possible to achieve those `std::string` typedefs in the same manner as the structs?

Comment: `typedef struct StructA {std::string str;} StringEventA;`. If you want the typedef's to count as different they must resolve to different types.

Comment: Not so much to do with the `typedef`. The first two are simple type aliases, while the struct definitions comprise their own distinct ypes.

Answer (score 7):

```
struct {std::string str;}
```

this defines a type with no name.

```
std::string
```

this names a type.

```
typedef TYPE name;
```

this creates an alias `name` for the type `TYPE`.

In the `struct{}` case, it provides a name for the otherwise unnamed type created on that line.

In the `std::string` case, it aliases a name for an already named thing.

So in one case you created 2 types.  `typedef` only gave them names.

```
template<class T, class Tag>
struct strong:T{
  using T::T;
};
```

this is a reasonable good strong typedef.

Far from perfect, but decent.

```
struct tagA;
struct tagB;
using StringEventA=strong<std::string, tagA>;
using StringEventB=strong<std::stings, tagB>;
```

the tag can be lots of things, not just structs.

```
template<class T, auto Tag>
struct strong:T{
  using T::T;
};
```

now the tag is any compile time value.

```
using StringEventA=strong<std::string, 'A'>;
using StringEventB=strong<std::stings, 'B'>;
```

such as a `char` literal.

Your compiler may not support `auto` template parameters.  Check.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is a `typedef` for a struct considered a unique type while a `typedef` for a `std::string` or other primitive is not?

`typedef` defines an alias for a type. It does not define a new type.

The lines

```
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventA;
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventB;
```

are equivalent to

```
struct AnonymousStruct1 {std::string str;};
typedef AnonymousStruct1 StringEventA;

struct AnonymousStruct2 {std::string str;};
typedef AnonymousStruct2  StringEventB;
```

Use of the anonymous `struct`s that are used to define the `typdef`s are not the same type  even though they are identical word for word.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers explain the theory very well, and there's really no need to add up upon the wording. But occasionally some people still want to see proving code for insight. So I wrote a small code for g++ that demonstrates what's going on here ([online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6b61715893fa1b)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

// Helper function for the raw char pointer gymnastics needed with __cxa_demangle
template<typename T> std::string get_typename() {
    char* type_name;
    int status;
    std::string result;
    type_name = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(),0,0,&status);
    result = std::string(type_name);
    free(type_name);
    return result;
}

// These are considered to be the same thing
typedef std::string StringEvent1;
typedef std::string StringEvent2;
// While these are considered to be different things
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEvent3;
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEvent4;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Name of StringEvent1: " << get_typename<StringEvent1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name of StringEvent2: " << get_typename<StringEvent2>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name of StringEvent3: " << get_typename<StringEvent3>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Name of StringEvent4: " << get_typename<StringEvent4>() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Name of StringEvent1: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
Name of StringEvent2: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
Name of StringEvent3: StringEvent3
Name of StringEvent4: StringEvent4
```

So we can clearly see what and why the compiler consideres to be the same or different.

The above code uses the [`typeid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator, to get info about the (underlying) types, and the compiler specific [`abi::__cxa_demangle()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) function to convert it into a human readable format.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, you use `typeedef` or not; when you declare with `struct`;

```
struct A {};
struct B {};


typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventA;
typedef struct {std::string str;} StringEventB;
```

both are different types anyway.

`std::string` already defined type, may hold different values but, type is always same; it's just you have two alias names for `std::string` type